# Apache Pig: Convert bag of tupple to single tupple

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm trying to convert a bag of tupples into a single tupple:

```
grunt> describe B;
B: {Comment: {tuple_of_tokens: (token: chararray)}}

grunt> dump B;
({(10),(123),(1234)})
```

I would like to get (10,123,1234) from B. I've tried using FLATTEN but this gives a new line for each tupple in the bag and that is not what I want. 
Is there any way to do this conversion without going to UDF ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BagToTuple()` function is already available in piggybank, you just download the `pig-0.11.0.jar` and set it in your classpath. For this you no need to write any UDF code.

**Download jar from this link:**
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadpig0110jar.htm

**Reference:**
    https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/BagToTuple.html

**Example:**
**input.txt**

```
{(10),(123),(1234)}
{(4),(5)}
```

**Pigscript:**

```
    A= LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (b:{t:(f1)});
    B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(BagToTuple(b));
    DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(10,123,1234)
(4,5)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted. I'm already using piggybank for others purposes but did not think in checking it for BagToTuple. I'll check piggybank in the future ! :)